# How long can a function be in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Java, the maximum size of a function is [65535 bytes](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4262078).

Is there any specified limits in ECMAScript?

What about known limitations in browsers?

Comment: just create one long enough to see..

Comment: I sure hope I never have to maintain whatever application that function goes in...

Comment: @JaredFarrish Of course not, but its still important information for a Javascript code generator (e.g. [Google's Dart](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/14/google_project_kill_javascript/)) to check if the generated code meets specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no defined limits to the maximum size of a *FunctionBody* in the ECMAScript specification, nor are there any ― as far as I'm aware ― documented limitations on the maximum sizes of function declarations in browsers.

Many browsers do have size limits on string lengths, for instance 512MB in Chrome, so any function created with the `Function` constructor could certainly not be larger than this limit, and it's possible the same or a similar limit applies to functions in parsed code too.